# How do I get the standard default.prop file back on the root file system?

Tags: rooting, stock-android, unrooting, stock-rom, factory-image

At the root file system on my Android phone, there's a file called default.prop.  Right now that's a non-standard file because of [CF Auto Root](http://autoroot.chainfire.eu/), but I want that file to be the stock version (1).

After what I have understood, /default.prop file is overwritten on every boot from a default.prop file within the boot partition.

My phone is rooted with CF-Auto-Root, but I've replaced the boot and bootloader partitions with [factory image versions](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images):

```
$ fastboot flash bootloader bootloader.img
$ fastboot flash boot boot.img
```

But *still* I get the non-stock default.prop file.  What am I doing wrong?

**(1)** This is because I'm trying to upgrade to Android 5.1, and right now I'm getting an error because "this device has google/omni_hammerhead/hammerhead:4.4.4/KTU84P/eng.dees_troy.20150214.172938:eng/test-keys".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just quote [Elluel on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/google-nexus-5/help/how-standard-default-prop-file-root-file-t3054023/post59430617#post59430617):

> Don't bother messing with reverting everything just to update, it is
>   extremely unlikely to work since as of Lollipop Google has changed the
>   OTA method to check the sum of the entire partition rather than only
>   what it cares about.
>
> Download the 5.1 factory images, and flash system.img, boot.img,
>   cache.img, radio.img and bootloader.img (don't flash userdata.img
>   unless you want to wipe all your data), then boot into a custom
>   recovery and flash the latest SuperSU
>   (http://download.chainfire.eu/supersu).

It doesn't answer the question here directly, but it ultimately solved what I was trying to achieve.